# Derivating with respect the parameter calcule $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\arctan(a\tan x)}{\tan x}dx$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Derivating with respect the parameter calcule $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\arctan(a\tan x)}{\tan x}dx$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "derivating with respect the parameter", could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BadamBaplan The OP probably mean to say "Differentiating with respect to the parameter $a$, calculate"

Comment: Otherwise known as *Feynman's trick* for differentiating under the integral sign. While he may have popularised the method in the early half of the twentieth century he was by no means the first person to use the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement the post by @MarkViola, let us show
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2x}= \frac{\pi}{2(a+1)}
\end{align}
assuming $a>0$.

Observe
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2x} = \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sec^2 x- \tan^2x}{1+a^2\tan^2x}\ dx
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2x}+ \frac{1}{a^2}\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{a^2\tan^2 x}{1+a^2\tan^2x}\ dx = \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+a^2\tan^2x}\ dx.
\end{align}
Next, notice the left hand side of the above identity is equal to
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2x}+ \frac{1}{a^2}\int^{\pi/2}_0 1- \frac{1}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}\ dx = \left(1-\frac{1}{a^2} \right)\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}+ \frac{\pi}{2a^2}.
\end{align}
and the right hand side by $u$-sub equals
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}\ dx = \frac{\pi}{2a}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{1}{a^2} \right)\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2 x} = \frac{\pi(a-1)}{2 a^2} \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ \int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2 x} = \frac{\pi}{2(a+1)}.
\end{align}

**Remark**: If we drop the condition $a>0$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}\ dx = \frac{\pi}{2|a|}
\end{align}
which leads to the conclusion
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{dx}{1+a^2\tan^2 x} = \frac{\pi}{2(|a|+1)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(a)$ be given by the integral

$$f(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\arctan(a\tan(x))}{\tan(x)}\,dx$$

Then, differentiating reveals

$$f'(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+a^2\tan^2(x)}\,dx=\frac{\pi/2 }{a+1}$$

Integrating and using $f(0)=0$ yields

$$f(a)=\frac\pi2\log(a+1)$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\tan(x)}\,dx=\frac\pi 2 \log(2)$$

Comment: There's a typo. It should read $\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{1}{1+a^2\tan^2 x}\ dx$.

Comment: @Jacky Chong...why?

Comment: Because $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan x = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: @JackyChong  how to integrate$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+a^2 \tan^2 x} dx$

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote?

Comment: @MarkViola  I don't know. I gave it an up vote.